# проблема с отображением title (+Ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

`<title><?=$title?></title>` < ok

`<title id="NewMess"><?=$title?></title>` <- если id="NewMess" не пуст, отображает "новое сообщение", а если пуст, то отображает URL сайта, место текста который содержится в $title.

mail.js:

```
function show_mail()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/include/mail.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
           $("#NewMess").html(html);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval('show_mail()',5000);
});
```

mail.php

```
<?
$mail = DB :: $dbs -> querySingle("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mail` WHERE `id_contact` = '".App::user()->id."' AND `read` = '0'",0);
if ($mail!=0) echo text($mail, array('нове повідомлення','нових повідомлень','нових повідомлень'));
?>
```

Как исправить?
С учетом того, что js подключается в конце страницы, а содержание $title определяется в начале страницы и условие `else echo $title;` в файле mail.php ничего не даст.
А если подключить js вначале, то тогда не работает увидомление.

Comment: А где вы определяете $title ?

Comment: $title = ('мой сайт');

require_once('include/head.php'); а в хеад уже хтмл шаблон.

Comment: Я правильно понял что вы хотите проверять уведомления каждые 5 секунд и если новых сообщений нет то отобразить просто `мой сайт` ?

Comment: да) именно так.

Comment: но, вместо "мой сайт" может быть любой текст. на каждой странице, перед инклудом head.php стоит $title = ('название страницы');

Comment: А где эти названия страниц хранятся ?

Comment: в переменной тайлт. ну к примеру. страница ban.php -> $title = ('Вы заблокированы'); require_once('include/head.php');  index.php -> $title = ('Главная'); require_once('include/head.php'); а вот файл head.php содержит <title id="mail_new_title"><?=$title?></title>

Comment: Можете записать значение в data атрибут и если mail.php возвращает пустой текст то брать значение из data аттрибута. Проблема с $title в mail.php заключается в том что сервер не знает на какой странице находится клиент в момент отправки AJAX запроса

Comment: @sergeyN я так и описал ниже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запишите в дата атрибуте заголовок по умолчанию.

```
<title data-default="<?= $title ?>"><?= $title ?></title>
```

После переработайте функцию таким образом чтобы когда приходит пустой ответ то выводился текст с дата атрибута.

```
function show_mail() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/include/mail.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            if (html.length != 0) $("title").html(html);
            else $('title').html($('title').data('default'));
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval('show_mail()', 2000);
});
```

И еще к слову давать тегу `title` идентификатор нет никакого смысла, т.к данный тег в документе может быть только один.

Comment: от души, все работает :) спасибо.

Comment: рад был помочь :)

Comment: а по поводу id, я на фейсбуке подсмотрел, там именно тайтл имеет айди

Comment: <title id="pageTitle">Facebook</title>

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/title можете почитать о теге `title` здесь явно указано что тег не имеет атрибутов. и смысла не вижу давать тегу который единственный в документе идентификатор.

Comment: @Aлександр если в двух словах, то когда мы через `JS` пытаемся найти тайтл (для манипуляций с ним), то для скрипта нет понятия - что тайтл в `DOM` может быть только один, а вот для `ID` - есть такое понятие. Поэтому поиск по `ID` будет быстрее чем по тегу.

Comment: @Manitikyl разница в миллионную долю секунды не видна человеческому глазу. Каждый делает по своему, лично я считаю что давать единственному элементу на странице для "быстродействия" идентификатор не рационально. При разработке читая код можно потеряться. `$('title')` явно указывает на заголовок а `$('#my_id')` можна присвоить любому элементу.

Comment: @Arendach Такие конторы очень сильно заботятся о быстродействии их сервиса. В интернете есть отчет исследований гугла, где они проверяли, как реквест страницы напрямую влиял на их трафик. Копеечка рубль бережет. Вас никто не заставляет так делать, делайте как вам удобно, я лишь сказал в чем смысл данной манипуляции и в чем её преимущество. Если для вас лучше сама запись `$('title')` и не важно что поиск будет осуществлен по всему `DOM`, то пусть так, даже поиск по `title:first` будет работать не так как `id`. фейсбуку важно не как им удобно, а как лучше со стороны производительности.